# How to "nicely" print out a tree without node information

Tags: python, tree

I'm dealing with trees where each node has no information, but can have any number of children. Currently, I'm using lists in Python to represent them. For example:

`[]` is a tree with just one node

`[[][][]]` is a tree where the top node has three children

`[[][[][[][]]]]` is a tree where the top node has two children, and the right child has two children, and the right child has two children.

You can see that the last tree is quite hard to read.

Is there a way to print out these trees that's somehow easier to read? (I know "easier" is subjective, so I would appreciate any suggestion which you think might be "easier".)

Comment: ... what would you *like* it to look like?

Comment: @HughBothwell That's exactly what I don't know. :) I just know that my current representation is quite hard to read (e.g. the last example `[[][[][[][]]]]`), so I was wondering if there's a representation that's easier to read.

Comment: Try printing each child on a newline with an added indent. That might make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tree = [[],[[],[[],[]]]]

def print_tree(tree, indent = ""):
    if len(tree) > 0:
        print indent + "["
        for child in tree:        
            print_tree(child, indent + "    ")
        print indent + "]"
    else:
        print indent + "[]"


print_tree(tree)
```

Comment: Also if you want an image check out graphviz and pydot.

Comment: And ubigraph and gephi while I'm about it.